# Suggested change of tag definition for Anaconda

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Seems like the vast majority of questions here with the tag [anaconda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anaconda) refer to issues with the [Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/) Python and R Data Science package, yet the formal definition of the `anaconda` tag here is "Questions about Anaconda, the kickstart system used by Fedora et al." In other words, the system installer.

Folks being folks, our users saw [anaconda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anaconda) and figured it meant the Data Science package instead of what y'all really meant. As of 2019-01-31, there are 62 posts with that tag, and 38 (61%) are about the Python and R Data Science package.

Wish to suggest two new tags replace [anaconda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anaconda):
`anaconda-OS-installer` or `anaconda-kickstarter`
and
`Anaconda-Python-R` or `Anaconda-DataScience`. Really don't care what they're named eventually, but completely removing the misused tag and offering two replacements which clarify the issue at hand seems reasonable.

Comment: Seems a reasonable idea, to me!  Have an upvote :-)

Comment: I would suggest putting the differentiator *first*, e.g. `kickstart-anaconda` and `r-anaconda` (or whatever makes more sense for the Python/R one).

Comment: (the idea being that if the user starts typing "anaconda", both tags show up, but the leading portion quickly distinguishes them); compare with going to https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags and searching for "script"

Comment: `python-anaconda` might perhaps be a better tag for the Python one. It might be mainly Python+R focussed just now, but these things tend to have a habit of scope creep?

Comment: Upvated, and I agree 100%. Frustrating, looking for install/kickstart related questions and finding Data Science stuff I know nothing about. :)

Comment: I've created the two new tags as per the answer below.

Comment: (Improvements to either excerpt or wiki are welcome; I simply got them started with *something*)

Answer (score 8):

I'll propose a solution to Answer this; please indicate (with voting) if this is a direction you like or not! These differ from the proposal in the Question mainly in swapping the nouns around.

- new tag: "[installer-anaconda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installer-anaconda)"
- new tag: "[datascience-anaconda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datascience-anaconda)"

I removed "kickstart" from my initial comment regarding the "installer" one because while it's closely related, it seems independent-enough to me.

The data science [Anaconda describes itself](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/) as a "distribution for data science; a package manager, an environment manager, a Python/R data science distribution, and a collection of over 1,500+ open source packages" -- which is a little longer than the 35 character limit. I went with "data science" from the sub-header and one of the features.

- We would also want to blacklist "anaconda" as ambiguous, in order to force a choice between one of the new tags.

Comment: This sounds like a solid plan to resolve this. I have been on a personal crusade the last several days to edit all of the 'data science' questions that are tagged Anaconda (with the kickstart-installer related tag). I would welcome a clear distinction. I don't _want_ to just arbitrarily strip the Anaconda tag without adding a proper replacement, but the questions are not always specifically Python related.

Comment: Happy to hear; I wanted to make sure there was a good amount of consensus before mucking with the tags. I see you're currently editing some posts to remove stray tags; might I suggest waiting until we have replacement tags so that it's easier to keep those posts appropriately tagged?

Comment: I can do that. My 'CDO' (its O.C.D., except alphabetized... *chuckle*) was acting up. I'll hold off until I see new tags.

Comment: Thank you! Given that only a percentage of U&L users visit Meta, and only a percentage of those care about these tags, I don't expect massive amounts of voting, although 29 votes on the Q is impressive. If you can wait a few more days, I'll revisit this to make sure there are no objections, then proceed. (And I've had [this link](http://www.badideatshirts.com/I-HAVE-CDO-ITS-LIKE-OCD-BUT-ALL-THE-LETTERS-ARE-IN-ALPHABETICAL-ORDER-AS-THEY-SHOULD-BE-T-SHIRT-P2366.aspx) bookmarked for longer than I can remember. Saving it for a birthday gift at some point!)

Comment: #TakeMyMoney =)

Comment: Once I see the new tags I will try to make an effort to go back (using my inbox messages) and add the new anaconda-datascience or whatever it ends up being to those other posts. Many of them seem to have activity and answers.

Comment: I've created the two new tags; please tackle the re-tagging at your convenience. Once [tag:anaconda] is empty, it should get removed automatically.