# datascience-anaconda env isn't being loaded - a better name might be needed

Tags: discussion, tags

After a [Suggested change of tag definition for Anaconda](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5166/70524), we got [installer-anaconda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installer-anaconda) and [datascience-anaconda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datascience-anaconda). Since that time, we have had [10 non-deleted questions in `installer-anaconda`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Binstaller-anaconda%5D%20is%3Aq%20created%3A2019-04-19..), of which 6 are actually about the other Anaconda. For comparison, in that time we have had [9 `datascience-anaconda` questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdatascience-anaconda%5D%20is%3Aq%20created%3A2019-04-22..) and I corrected the tags of some of them.

The split didn't work out well. Should [datascience-anaconda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datascience-anaconda) be renamed to [conda-anaconda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conda-anaconda) or something? The problem might be that Conda is also used for installing software, so [installer-anaconda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installer-anaconda), despite the tag excerpt, sounds like a match at first glance.